# Lifting a sails app on Heroku fails

Tags: mongodb, heroku, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm not able to lift a Sails api application in a production environment on Heroku to connect against a mongolab db. This works well when running in a local setup. The Heroku logs shows the following...

```
`
/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:138:13
    at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:20
    at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:239:13
    at _arrayEach (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:91:13)
    at _each (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:82:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:238:9)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:215:22)
    at Object.module.exports.adapter.teardown (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:137:22)
    at /app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:244:19
    at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:122:13
    at _each (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
    at Object.async.each (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:9)
    at Sails.hook.teardown (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:241:13)
    at Sails.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:166:7)
`
```

Running sails version 0.11.2

Sails-mongo version 0.11.4

The process.env variables has been added and verified

connection.js

```
`
mongodb: {
  adapter: 'sails-mongo',
  url : process.env.CONNECTION_URL,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.PORT_NR,
  user: proces.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB
},
```

`
env/production.js

```
`
connections : {
  mongoLive: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url : process.env.CONNECTION_URL
  }
},
models: {
  connection: 'mongoLive'
},
`
```

development.js

```
`
connections : {
  mongoDev: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    database: 'threads_db'
  }
},

models: {
  connection: 'mongoDev'
}
`
```

Procfile

```
`
web: npm start
`
```

package.json

```
`
"scripts": {
  "debug": "node debug app.js",
  "start": "sails lift"
},
`
```

models.js has been set to

```
`
 connection: 'mongodb',
`
```

So, running this locally works fine with both a connection to a local mongo db and the remote mongolab db but deployment to Heroku fails. Sees to me that I'm missing something in the setup. Help with this appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the master version of sails-mongo.

package.json

```
"sails": "git+https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git"
```

Then once deployed to heroku restarted the dyno with

```
`heroku ps:scale web=1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Known bug. Check out https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/352

You will probably need to `npm install sails-mongo#master --save` until it is released.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I updated the sails-mongo version in package.json to "sails-mongo": "git+https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo.git" and pushed to heroku but with no luck.

Comment: that is no good. I had the same issue on modulus hosting and I might have also updated waterline to the latest as well. I don't have access to that project right now, as soon as I do I will attempt to update my answer.

Comment: Are there any workarounds available. Did you try any other mongo adapter, if there's any other options available?

Comment: Trying using the latest sails `"sails": "git+https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git"` I was getting the same error

Comment: Tried this before, but did not work for me on heroku. Does it work for you?

Comment: I did. It might be a race condition where the connection is also not ready. Are you able to connect to the remote database on heroku?

Comment: No, not able to connect with the remote db on heroku,works fine from my localhost

Answer (score 0):

For those if the accepted answer didn't work after deploying in heroku , try to change the node js, sails-mongo versions along with sails and check.

It worked for me after changing the versions to the below:

1.nodejs - 14.15.1

2.sails - ^1.5.2

3.sails-mongo - ^2.0.0